# multiple human detection using HOG features

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, computer-vision, svm

I am doing a project on multiple human detection in static images using HOG features with SVM (matlab) in matlab. I have taken 20 single human cropped images for positive training. Do i have to take multiple humans in image as training in order to detect multiple persons?  now my software detecting only one human even there are 5 persons in the image. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: This website might help you: http://www.geocities.ws/talh_davidc/

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to train your human detector with **single** humans.
2. When you start your detector you have to make sure that it continues searching even when it found the first match.

A first, very basic (and error-prone) approach would be to subdivide the image into multiple overlapping tiles and running the detector on each of those. This way you could check if the detector is able to recognize the different types of humans. If it does not, you have found the bug: the detector itself is insufficiently trained. If it does, you just have to force it to keep looking even after the first hit.